# Where can I find all the Diamondbacks in the Great Train Robbery?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

I'm once again working on my achievements, but haven't located all Diamondbacks.

Does anyone have a map or something where I can find all of them?

Bonus points if you can also pinpoint to the Defiler bones!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image: There are 6 abandoned Diamondback Tanks at various points on the map. You can find them all to get 6 free Diamondback Tanks. The first three have their location revealed to you, but the other three are farther away and require more effort to find. One Diamondback Tank is on the same high ground area that the left most Diamondback that's revealed to you is on. It's at the top center part of the map. The fifth Diamondback Tank is around the middle in the map, on a small high ground platform next to the middle Train track. The sixth Diamondback Tank is to the southeast of your base, also on a high ground. It's in between the middle and bottom tracks. The fifth and sixth Diamondbacks are lightly guarded.]

There are 3 Defiler bones that are scattered across the map:

- One bone is located south of your starting position, and you can see it from your starting position.
- The second bone is located to the northwest of your base, near the Train tracks. The third Defiler bone is located directly south of your starting position, next to the bottom Train tracks. The first two are revealed on your mini map at the start of the mission.
- The third is revealed by the second train. In all cases, they are all revealed by the 5 minute mark, and none of them are guarded, at the beginning of the mission. Get them as soon as they are revealed, before it becomes harder.

Source: [TL Wiki - Starcraft II - Campaign - The Great Train Robbery](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Campaign/The_Great_Train_Robbery)